# How can I bold just one column in my dataframe so I can export to an excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been reading documentation and some questions here, but I only found solutions with conditions, I have some columns in my dataframe that I want to bold and then concatenate.

My dataframe it´s like this:

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | Produc1 |
| Jhon | product2 |

I want all the values in my column(Paul, Jhon) to be bold so I can export that to an excel.

Comment: It's very confusing to read "values in column names". to rename the column names use: `df.set_axis(map(str.upper, df.columns), axis=1)` to rename the values in a column then `df[column] = df.column.str.upper()`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I don´t want to rename the values, I want them to be bold, the names Paul and John to be bold

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```py
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'font-weight: bold;', subset='Name')\
        .to_excel('output.xlsx')
```